# Catch event in different module

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventemitter

I've created event in some module inside my node App and I want to catch this event in other module,I try the following which doesnt work

the module which raise the event

```
EventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter;

function updatePort(port) {
  ...
  var ee = new EventEmitter();
  ee.emit("AppDef");

}
```

Now I want in **different** module to catch this event and to print something to the console

```
EventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter;
var ee = new EventEmitter();
ee.on("AppDef", function () {
  console.log('Port is defiend ' + port);
})
```

I think that the problem is with the `new` that I did twice but not sure how to overcome this...

Comment: You need to share the same event emitter instance between the modules.

Comment: @thefourtheye - can you show me please how as answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, you are creating two different `EventEmitter` instances and you are emitting from one instance and listening for the event in the other.

To fix this, you need to share the same `EventEmitter` instance between the modules

**Module 1**

```
var EventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter;
var ee = new EventEmitter();

function updatePort(port) {
  ...
  // emit the port as well
  ee.emit("AppDef", port);
}

// export the EventEmitter instance
module.exports.ee = ee;
```

**Module 2**

```
var mod1 = require('./module1');

// Attach the listener on the EventEmitter instance exported by module1
mod1.ee.on('AppDef', function(port) {
    console.log('Port is defined ' + port);
});
```

Comment: Thanks I try it, This is the only way to do it ? The problem is that I create dependency between the module...I know that I've it already but there is some other way to do it ?

Comment: You can try refactoring your code in such a way that you ll listen to the event in the same module which generates it.

Comment: Thanks 1+,last question :) you talking about refactor the code ...Currenlty I need to update some port So I do it in specific module and I want to send this event to the server.js since I want to print to the console new port which I found...is it OK?

Comment: Ya, to me it looks fine.